# Text on Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary) is a little bit transparent by default. Can I make it 100% opaque for ALL Text composables?

Tags: kotlin, text, android-jetpack-compose

`Text()` composable draws text with some transparency on surfaces with primary color:

```
val Purple500 = Color(0xFF6200EE)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Purple500,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200
)


ColorsTestTheme {
    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary) {
        Column {
            Text("Android", fontSize = 55.sp)
            Text("Android", color = Color.White, fontSize = 55.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: text on first line is not opaque]

Can I make text 100% opaque for **ALL** `Text()` composables with some **BUILT-IN** API?

Usually I get design mockups with opaque text :)

I realize that I can implement my own composable like `OpaqueText(<params>, @Composable () -> Unit)`
and use it to draw opaque text :). I'm just wondering if there is a way to configure something in compose in order to achieve the same result with built-in `Text()` composable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a bug. I think `LocalContentAlpha` should be updated depending on current background according to [Material guidelines](https://material.io/design/color/text-legibility.html#text-backgrounds). Currently it's only being set in `MaterialTheme` according to this:

> Dark text on light backgrounds (shown here as #000000 on #FFFFFF) applies the following opacity levels: High-emphasis text has an opacity of 87%

As a tmp fix, to override this behaviour you can provide a `LocalContentAlpha` value with `CompositionLocalProvider` for part of your application, or you can embed it in your theme:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ColorsTestTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkThemeColors
    } else {
        LightThemeColors
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = shapes,
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalContentAlpha provides 1f,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: ...though I'm pretty sure there's a bug in how this is being handled (I think it's reading `LocalContentColor` at the wrong point), because the text is _still_ a lighter opacity if you make the Surface, say, #BBBBBB.  Your fix should work in either case, though.

Comment: @RyanM yes, I think it's expected to be recalculated depending on the background, but right not it's only getting set inside `MaterialTheme`

Comment: Hm, I had several concerns about solution which uses LocalContentAlpha for whole theme. But I've checked it right now and it looks like it doesn't provide any negative side-effects on behavior of other built-in composables.  Thanks guys!